# SQL trigger to merge totals to parent table (with cancelled column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger to merge a column value to its parent table. In this case the InvoiceTotal gets added/subtracted to the Account's InvoiceTotal

```
WITH Deltas as (
    SELECT AccountID, Sum(InvoiceTotal) as InvoiceTotal From inserted Group By AccountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AccountID, Sum(InvoiceTotal * -1) as InvoiceTotal From deleted Group By AccountID
),
Merged as
    (Select AccountID, Sum(InvoiceTotal) InvoiceTotal From Deltas Group by AccountID)
Update Account set InvoiceTotal = Account.InvoiceTotal + Merged.InvoiceTotal From Merged Where Account.AccountID = Merged.AccountID;
```

Now I have a new column called IsCancelled in the Invoice Table. How can I modify the above trigger to handle that? If the invoice is cancelled, the Account total should reduce and if IsCancelled is set to 0, it should increase.

Is it possible to do the above task in one single SQL statement?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than storing the total in the account table, I'd seriously consider using a `VIEW` that always works from the detail lines - that way, it's always correct and you don't need triggers at all. If performance was a concern, it looks like such a view could be an indexed view (which stores its results and is automatically maintained by SQL Server, again without needing to write any triggers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the IsCancelled flag to your invoice table, you are saying that when an invoice is cancelled, then you want to remove that invoice total amount from the account balance. Another way to say this is that when IsCancelled = 1 then the InvoiceTotal should be treated as 0, and the account balance updated accordingly.  For ex: if the old invoice total was 100, and then that invoice is cancelled, then you should subtract 100 from the account table (inserted/new value of 0 minus deleted/old value of 100).  In that case, you can update your trigger query as follows.

```
WITH Deltas as (
    SELECT AccountID, Sum(case when IsCancelled = 0 then InvoiceTotal else 0 end) as InvoiceTotal From inserted Group By AccountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AccountID, Sum(case when IsCancelled = 0 then InvoiceTotal * -1 else 0 end) as InvoiceTotal From deleted Group By AccountID
),
Merged as
    (Select AccountID, Sum(InvoiceTotal) InvoiceTotal From Deltas Group by AccountID)
Update Account set InvoiceTotal = Account.InvoiceTotal + Merged.InvoiceTotal From Merged Where Account.AccountID = Merged.AccountID;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle with examples of this in action. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0246/16

Comment: This answer is assuming that the purpose of the new "IsCancelled" flag is to allow an invoice to act as if it were deleted, while allowing users to still be able to view the original invoice details even after it is cancelled.

Comment: @Arun have you tried this solution? When I tested this out it worked on both single and multi row updates, inserts, and deletes.

Comment: @BaleTech, Sorry for the late response. Yes I tried it. What happens when the IsCancelled flag, the AccountID and the Amount are all modified together in one single statement. The above SQL works only when any ONE of the above fields are modified. In fact if the AccountID is modified, the above trigger will fail

Comment: It shouldn't fail if the AccountID is modified or if all columns are modified.... updating my SQL Fiddle and will send the link in just a minute

Comment: @Arun this does work even when all values are modified in the same statement, and the trigger does not fail if the AccountID is modified (unless the AccountID is not valid, i.e. does not exist in Account table).  Here is an updated SQL Fiddle. See examples 9.2 and 9.3. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0246/24

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Deltas as (
    SELECT AccountID, CASE WHEN IsCancelled=0 THEN Sum(InvoiceTotal) ELSE Sum(InvoiceTotal*-1) END as InvoiceTotal From inserted Group By AccountID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT AccountID, CASE WHEN IsCancelled=0 THEN Sum(InvoiceTotal*-1) ELSE Sum(InvoiceTotal) END  as InvoiceTotal From deleted Group By AccountID
),
Merged as
    (Select AccountID, Sum(InvoiceTotal) InvoiceTotal From Deltas Group by AccountID)
Update Account set InvoiceTotal = Account.InvoiceTotal + Merged.InvoiceTotal From Merged Where Account.AccountID = Merged.AccountID;
```

a case when condition might help you on this.

updated on the deleted portion.

Comment: Thanks, what happens when a cancelled invoice is deleted? I think we'll need another case in the deleted too right?

Comment: yes, @Arun, you are right. I missed that. Please refer to the updated query.

Comment: That `Deltas` CTE makes no sense. Remember, `inserted` and `deleted` can contain *multiple* rows - so you may have a mixture of rows, some of which have `IsCancelled` equal to 0, and others where it's 1.

Comment: good point on that, @Arun you might consider that if your inserted might combine of mixture.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's better that use Indexed view instead of trigger in order to have total price of your invoices. I suggest you that have following indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_InvoiceTotal With SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    SELECT AccountId, 
             SUM (CASE WHEN IsCancelled=0 THEN InvoiceTotal ELSE -InvoiceTotal END) as InvoiceTotal,
             Count_Big(*) AS c
    FROM Deltas 
    GROUP By AccountId
End


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_InvoiceTotal ON dbo.vw_InvoiceTotal (AccountId)
```

In this way, SQL Server sync your indexed view automatically by internal trigger on your table. and you can use this view with above performance.

```
SELECT * FROM vw_InvoiceTotal WITH(NOEXPAND)
```

If you need to have InvoiceTotal column in your mastertable I suggest that you have above Indexed view and have following trigger on Deltas table:

```
Create Trigger tr_sync_deltas on dbo.deltas
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS Begin
    Update MasterTable
    Set InvoiceTotal = ISNULL(i.InvoiceTotal,0)
    From (
       Select AccountId From Inserted
       Union
       Select AccountId From deleted
       )z
    Left Join dbo.vw_InvoiceTotal i on i.AccountId = z.AccountId
    Where MasterTable.AccountId = z.AccountId
End
```

Comment: Needs `COUNT_BIG(*)` in the select list inside the view.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi and Damien, this is definitely an option I was thinking about. There's a specific reason I need it the other way - I have a ER framework which retrieves data based on a REST api. Having another view adds to the number of entities, permissions and extra coding while retrieving both invoice and totals together. I wish I could explain in detail, but this is not an option for me right now.

Comment: @Arun. I Edit my post. please check this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it is possible on SQL Server by using a MERGE with a WHEN MATCHED/NOT MATCHED construct, you can add as many AND conditions as you need.

See Microsoft's reference on [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) specifically, see example B. **Using MERGE to perform UPDATE and DELETE operations on a table in a single statement**

I'm not pasting it in my response, since I do not have the time right now to re-factor the example to match your scenario, I will try to. Either way, this should likely give you what you need.